# Error while running make to install `Sumo`

Tags: 15.04, make

When I tried to install Sumo-0.26.0 I am getting this error while running `make` command:

> "../../src/utils/vehicle/IntermodalRouter.h:109:35: error: there are no arguments to ‘fabs’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘fabs’ must be available [-fpermissive]"

Comment: Second test : The 32bits Ubuntu 15.04 + sumo-0.26 → No issues.

Answer (score 1):

---

Your post is tagged 15.04, unknown version. This command will tell : $ `uname -m`

First test ... with no issues : The 64bits Ubuntu 15.04. A valid sumo-src-0.26.0.tar.gz :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/sumo/files/sumo/version%200.26.0/sumo-src-0.26.0.tar.gz/download

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++ autoconf libtool libxerces-c-dev libfox-1.6-dev libgdal-dev libproj-dev
$ tar xvf sumo-src-0.26.0.tar.gz
$ cd sumo-0.26.0/
$ ./configure
$ make : No errors.
$ sudo make install : OK too.
```

---